# QGIS Midvatten stratigraphy plot issues

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, geology, plot, midvatten

When I use the stratigraphy plot function in Midvatten on an East Anglian coast quaternary data set (West 1980) that I have been digitizing, I find that the upper layers of strata disappear at the top of the window as I expand the window. Also not all the strata get the right colour coding and some strata appear out of sequence. Here is a screen shot example with relevant attribute tables:

[image: stratigraphy plot with attribute tables]

Hopefully the posted screen shot will be expandable so the attribute tables are legible. Chalk should be the base layer in borehole HC but it comes out as the second layer in the plot and only 7 out of 13 strata are visible.

I have:

- a) checked that the window chopping off the top of the plot is not associated with the hi-resolution screen by trying the same plot on a computer with a lower resolution screen.
- b) renumbered 'stratid' to start every 'obs_point' from 1 (originally I numbered the 'stratid' consecutively for the whole dataset 1-1370).
- c) cut the number of facies from 74 geoshort to 25 strata with the hope that simplification might help.(Josef Kallgarden  suggested a and b).

What else might I try to fix these issues?

Comment: I think you could get more attention if you report this as a bug of Midvatten in their bugtracker

Comment: @Marco before I made this post I did email this as a bug report to Josef Kallgarden. He suggested that if after testing on a computer with a lower resolution screen it looked like the cutting off problem was a screen resolution issue I should add the details to /qgis-midvatten-plugin/issues/248. He also suggested I post the rest here after trying his b) suggestion. I am therefore not sure if these issues that I am talking about are bugs or something I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add a layer with depthtop starting at 0 as your first layer for one of the obsids.

Your HH-obsid would then look like:

```
obsid stratid depthtop depthbot  
HH 1 0 19.4  
HH 2 19.4 19.5  
HH 3 19.5 19.9
```

There is an issue where gaps in depthtop-depthbot causes the layers to be compressed at the top of the stratigraphy plot (it's fixed in another branch of the plugin).

But I'm not sure if caused the cut of at the top of your stratigraphy.

I tried all the color codes in your screenshot and they seemed to work for me.

Comment: your suggestion solved all three problems. The color codes were matplotlib color codes rather than qt color codes entered in the qt column so its a bit surprising that they work.